# Bloqueado por CORS

Tags: laravel-5, php5, angular7, cors

Estimados: Tengo el siguiente problema, subí una a Api a un servidor, (Back-end con Laravel 5.2, Front-end con Angular 7), no tuve problemas tanto al trabajar levantando el servicio localmente como desde el servidor, y la aplicación quedo funcionando. Cuando necesité hacer varias modificaciones, baje el proyecto para probar todo localmente y luego volver a subirlo. Lo curioso es que ahora cada vez que desde el front realizo una petición POST obtengo el ya conocido error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/feeders' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

Durante el desarrollo a este problema lo había resuelto, colocando en dentro de cada controlador de Laravel, y en cada método las siguientes cabeceras:

```
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

Probé con el Postman, y la API responde correctamente. 
Solo me queda aportar como dato adicional, es que en principio lo desarrolle con una versión de PHP 7.x.x. y como era incompatible con del servidor, me cambié a la 5.5.12, es la que está en mi pc actualmente. Bueno, espero que exista otra alternativa para la solución. Un abrazo y desde ya Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Create un Middleware para que añada las cabeceras en todas las peticiones que pasen por ese controlador.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

Y añadelo a `app/Http/Kernel.php` para poder usarlo

```
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'           => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic'     => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings'       => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can'            => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest'          => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle'       => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
// ...
        'cors'           => Cors::class,
    ];
```

En el controlador lo puedes poner por defecto

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth:api');
        $this->middleware('throttle:60,1');
        $this->middleware('cors');
    }
```

Comment: Gracias Manuel. Te comento que lo que me propones NO logró solucionar el problema. Nuevamente, : ( , gracias por el aporte.